# Delete or replace an image in PowerPoint using OfficeJS

Tags: powerpoint, office-js, add-in, office-addins

I am building an Office JS add-in for PowerPoint, which operates on images of a certain type. I want to be able to delete or replace/update such images, but I cannot find the correct APIs to do this either on a single selected image or even any old image(s).

The [Office JS API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.document?view=office-js) does not appear to have any PowerPoint specific methods, so it seems I will have to rely on what is available in the Common API. There is no obvious delete method visible.

I am already calling [GetFileAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.document?view=office-js#getfileasync-filetype--options--callback-) (similar to [this guide](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/blob/master/docs/includes/file-get-the-whole-document-from-an-add-in-for-powerpoint-or-word.md)) in order to look at the file contents. I could presumably modify those contents, but haven't tried, since I cannot see an API that allows me to re-save those modifications.

Have I missed any useful info?

Comment: It seems that this is the [UserVoice page for requesting more PowerPoint functionality](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/19543288-open-up-more-functionality-for-powerpoint-in-offic).